# Using an import text data in After Effects CS5

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs5, after-effects

I am using Flash CS5 to generate an array of the notes in a midi file. Basically I store data such as time of the note, note duration, pitch, scale, volume, etc...

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I export all these data in order to use it in after effects (as a txt file? other formats?);
2. How do I use the exported file in After Effects later on: How do I tell After Effects when to start playing a note in a specific time? how do I associate note height with a specific feature (lets say - square width) - and so on.

I DO know some basic coding in after effect (how to associate elements inside After - such as volume and opacity) but I need to understand how to deal with an exported file (and in which format to generate it).

Comment: Okay, I found out how to convert a midi file into an *.csv file, which kind of looks like a big excel sheet. (I used it with this small tool http://www.tima.demon.co.uk/midianal.htm - it gives me quiet a detailed view of the midi - very cool!) - now I just need to understand how to use it in AE. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of Midianal. The URL has changed. It is now available at http://www.tima.uk.com

Apart from reading the file, the app includes a small demonstration of how the data could be used to create a script for After Effects. But otherwise, it is for the User to write their own code, using the data from the CSV (spreadsheet) file.